# IllegalArgumentException in servlet (JavaEE) using Glassfish4

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, illegalargumentexception

I have a servlet that is used to retrieve a user stored in a DB in JavaEE.

When I call the servlet I get the following error from Glassfish4

```
type: Exception report

message: Internal Server Error

description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennis.nicola.GetPlayersApi

root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennis.nicola.GetPlayersApi

root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Local ejb-ref name=com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennis.nicola.GetPlayersApi/playerEjb,Local 3.x interface =com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennis.nicola.PlayerEJB resolved to intra-app EJB PlayerEJB in module scuolatennisnicola-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,ejb-link=PlayerEJB,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session into class com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennis.nicola.GetPlayersApi: Can not set com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennis.nicola.PlayerEJB field com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennis.nicola.GetPlayersApi.playerEjb to com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennis.nicola.GetPlayersApi

root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennis.nicola.PlayerEJB field com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennis.nicola.GetPlayersApi.playerEjb to com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennis.nicola.GetPlayersApi
```

The message seems state that the servlet is assigned to the EJB, but how can this happen? Or did I misinterpret the message?

What's strange is that just after this error message is displayed, if I try again to reload the page a 404 message is returned, as if the servlet was "undeployed" from the application and the only way to see again the same error message is to redeploy the application.
This is the servlet:

```
<imports...>

/**
 * Servlet implementation class GetPlayersApi
 * 
 * The API is the following: if nothing is present retrieves all the players if
 * ordered=true, retrieves all the players ordered if email=<email> retrieve the
 * player with the given email
 */
@WebServlet("/api/getPlayers")
public class GetPlayersApi extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // The list of the News to store the query in the DB
    List<Player> players;

    // Inject the News bean to get the data from DB
    @EJB
    PlayerEJB playerEjb;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public GetPlayersApi() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // get the map of the request parameters
        HashMap<String, String[]> map = (HashMap<String, String[]>) request.getParameterMap();

        // if no parameters are given
        if (map.size() == 0)
            // retrieve all the tags currently in the DB
            players = playerEjb.findPlayers();

        // else if ordered=true
        else if (map.get("ordered") != null && map.get("ordered")[0] == "true") {

            // get the Players in social ranking order
            players = playerEjb.findRankingOrderedPlayers();

        } else {

            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            Player player = playerEjb.findPlayerFromEmail(email);
            if (player != null)
                players.add(player);

        }

        // convert the result in JSON format and put them in the response
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(players);
        response.getWriter().append(array.toString());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public PlayerEJB getPlayerEJB() {
        return playerEjb;
    }

    public void setPlayerEJB(PlayerEJB pl) {
        playerEjb = pl;
    }

}
```

and this is the PlayerEJB class

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class PlayerEJB {
    // Inject the EntityManager to persist the LocationData entity
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "scuolaTennisNicolaPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * This method return the list of Player entities currently stored in the DB
     * 
     * @return a List of News objects
     */
    public List<Player> findPlayers() {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findAllPlayers");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    /**
     * This method retrieves from the DB the persisted player with the given
     * email
     * 
     * @param email
     *            the email of the player to be retrieved from the DB
     * @return the player with the given email that was persisted in the DB
     */
    public Player findPlayerFromEmail(String email) {

        // create the query
        String s = "SELECT p FROM Player p WHERE p.email = '" + email + "'";
        Query query = em.createQuery(s);

        // query the DB
        List<Player> list = (List<Player>) query.getResultList();
        // if the list is not empty return the first item in the list
        if (list.size() > 0)
            return list.get(0);
        else
            return null;
    }

    /**
     * This method return the list of Player entities currently stored in the DB
     * in social ranking order
     * 
     * @return a List of News objects
     */
    public List<Player> findRankingOrderedPlayers() {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findAllPlayersInRankingOrder");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    /**
     * This method remove all the Player entities currently stored in the DB
     */
    public void removePlayers() {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("removeAllPlayers");
        query.executeUpdate();
    }

    /**
     * This method remove the Player entities currently stored in the DB with a
     * given name and surname;
     * 
     * @param name
     *            the name of the player to be deleted
     * @param surname
     *            the surname of the player to be deleted
     */
    public void removePlayersWithName(String name, String surname) {
        // create the query
        String s = "DELETE FROM Player p WHERE p.name = '" + name + "' AND p.surname = '" + surname + "'";
        Query query = em.createQuery(s);

        query.executeUpdate();
    }

    /**
     * This method remove the Player entities currently stored in the DB with a
     * given name and surname;
     * 
     * @param name
     *            the name of the players to be deleted
     * @param surname
     *            the surname of the players to be deleted
     */
    public void removePlayersWithName(String[] name, String[] surname) {

        if (name.length != surname.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The two arrays arae not of the same length");
        // create the query
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            String s = "DELETE FROM Player p WHERE p.name = '" + name[i] + "' AND p.surname = '" + surname[i] + "'";
            Query query = em.createQuery(s);

            query.executeUpdate();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method remove the Player entities currently stored in the DB with a
     * given name and surname;
     * 
     * @param name
     *            the name of the players to be deleted
     * @param surname
     *            the surname of the players to be deleted
     */
    public void updatePlayersWithEmail(Player player) {

        if (player == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument cannot be null");

        String[] parts = { "p.name", "p.surname", "p.password", "p.age", "p.officialRanking", "p.phone", "p.email", "p.emailChallenger", "p.socialRanking",
                "p.role" };

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            String queryString = "UPDATE Player p SET " + parts[i] + "WHERE p.email = '" + player.getEmail();
            Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
            query.executeUpdate();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method persist a Player entity
     * 
     * @param data
     *            The Player entity to be persisted
     * @return the same Player entity that has just been persisted
     */
    public Player createPlayer(Player data) {
        em.persist(data);
        return data;
    }

}
```

Comment: does the error still occur if you comment out the `@PersistenceContext` annotation?  That will help you determine if the issue is the annotations on your EJB class, or if the issue is injecting the EntityManager into your EJB.  It has to be one of the two.

Comment: I'll try and I'll post the results. But what could be the reason of this error?

Comment: the reason of the error is that the `PlayerEJB` cannot be injected into the `GetPlayersAPI` servlet.

Comment: The result of commenting the @PersistentContext annotation is clearly a NPE the first time I use the EntityManager  (when the query is created in FindPlayerFromEmail(String)). I just tried it.

Comment: but does the `PlayerEJB` get injected to the `GetPlayersAPI` successfully?

Comment: I think so, otherwise I would have got the IllegalArgumentException before the NPE, i.e. when the playerEjb.getPlayersFromEmail(String) got fired.

Comment: In any case, when I uncommented the annotation the app started working correctly. If you know what could be the cause please answer the question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments on the OP, we have narrowed down the problem to the `@PersistenceContext EntityManager` not injecting in the `PlayerEJB`.

Without additional information, it is hard to tell what the exact problem is, but it is likely one of the following:

- Ensure the unitName `scuolaTennisNicolaPU` corresponds to the persistenceUnit defined in `META-INF/persistence.xml` such as this: 
  `<persistence-unit name="scuolaTennisNicolaPU">`
- Check earlier in logs to see what the issue is with injecting the `EntityManager`, this is the root problem, not the fact that the EJB is failing to inject into the Servlet.
- Ensure that your EJB is packaged with a `beans.xml` located in the `META-INF` directory.

---

If none of these things resolve your problem, additional information is needed, try updating your question with:

- Earlier exception messages indicating why the `EntityManager` failed to inject into the `PlayerEJB`.
- Your `persistence.xml` configuration

Comment: I didn't change anything, if not commenting and uncommenting the annotation. In any case it resolved the issue